# Prettyprinting Spring Boot JSON RESTful response in browser using thymeleaf

Tags: json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I would like to print the json response from a RESTful request in the browser in a easy human readable format, keeping json's linebreaks and indentations.

My current code saves the json response in a String and prints the string without any formatting.

In RESTFulController.java

```java
@Controller
public class RESTFulControllerController {

    @RequestMapping("myrequest")
    public String myRequest(Model model) {

        //--> Initializations
        RestTemplate rest_template= new RestTemplate();
        String url = "https://example.com/api";

        //--> Create http request
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        MultiValueMap<String, String> body_map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body_map.add("resource_id", "value_of_resource_id");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request_entity = new HttpEntity<>(body_map, headers);

        //--> Post http request 
        String response = rest_template.postForObject(url, request_entity, String.class);

        //--> Add data for display
        model.addAttribute("response", response);

        return "print_response";

}
```

In templates/print_response.html

```html
<body>
    [[${response}]] 
</body>
```

There is no need for further processing the response, it will be used only for its visualization in the browser. Is it better to do the formatting in the controller or in the template? and how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to convert your response string to a json object and then back to a indented string:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object json = objectMapper.readValue(response, Object.class);
String indented = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                               .writeValueAsString(json);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I had to change the thymeleaf template to display the linebreaks:

 [(${#strings.replace( #strings.escapeXml( response ),T(java.lang.System).getProperty('line.separator'),'&lt;br /&gt;')})] 

I am not sure if there is a more direct approach that will also show the indentation